# PostAsJson could not post data

Tags: asp.net, json.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jsonserializer

I have Web api method like below. The Web API is developed in`Classic .Net 4.6.2`

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DocumentDTO>> GetDocuments([FromBody]IEnumerable<string> documentNames)
    {
        return await _domainService.GetDocuments(documentNames);
    }
```

Then I have `ASP.Net Core` client that was using HttpClient to post data. I have my own extension method that serializes the input using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` and post it and then de-serializes the response

```
    public static async Task<TResult> MyPostMethodAsync<TSource, TResult>(this HttpClient httpClient, TSource source, string url)
    {
        // serialize the input
        var content = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

       //post json string
        var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent).ConfigureAwait(false);

        //ensures ok response
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

      // get response string
        var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

      //de-serialize the response
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(result)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

The method above working fine. Note that its using `PostAsync` method.

Then I changed the above method to make use of `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method that is available in `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`. So the new method looks like below

```
    public static async Task<TResult> MyPostMethodAsync<TSource, TResult>(this HttpClient httpClient, TSource source, string url)
    {
       // post as json
        var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<TSource>(url, source).ConfigureAwait(false);

      // Ensures response is okay
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

       // get response string
        var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // de-seriazlize the response
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(result)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

However the `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method does not post any data? The Web API Method always receive empty collection for documentnames parameter. (I'm also using my extension method to POST data to additional web api methods as well, but all POST methods receives null values or empty collection)

I am guessing its serialization/deserialization issue but I am not sure which serializer .Net 4.6.2 & .Net Core uses by default.

Comment: please show what is your 'Tsource source'. It works for me if I use List<string> as source for example.